# How to create trigger on linkserver?

Tags: sql-server

We have two sql servers(e.g server1 & server2). We have created table on server1 and used as linkserver on server2.Also we have trying to create trigger on that table via server2 but its throws an error.So please let me know how to create insert trigger using linkserver?

Comment: What type of trigger? Why are you trying to create a trigger on Server 1 from Server 2? Connect to Server 1 and create the trigger there.

Comment: what code did you run? What exact error did you get? Please be clear and specific about your problem. Seems a bit odd to try and define the trigger from server2 though - why is that necessary? Just log into server1 and create it there, like you did for creating the table.

Comment: We have requirements like this.

Comment: @Pankaj requirements like what? Your comment does not answer any of the questions Larnu or I have asked you. We cannot help you until you provide more information.

Comment: Then at least show us your attempt. And I still suggest you create the trigger from Server 1. The fact that you have been given these requirements doesn't mean you should; especially when they're bad requirements. This sounds like non-technical parts of the  business driving the technical side of it; and that never works. Non-Technical users are (unsurprisingly) aren't technical and don't understand what systems can (and can't) do.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec ('
use mydb;

create table dbo.testtable(id int);

exec(''
create trigger testtrigger on dbo.testtable 
for insert
as
begin
    select object_name(@@procid), *
    from inserted;

end
'');

') at linked_server_name;
go

exec ('insert into mydb.dbo.testtable(id) values (1), (2), (3)') at linked_server_name;
go
exec ('drop table mydb.dbo.testtable') at linked_server_name;
```